# How to install flink on raspberry-pi using docker?

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, apache-flink

I want to set up a cluster of edge-computing, therefore, I need to install the flink on the raspberry-pi.
I am using the raspberry 4b and the system is raspbian. Version is:

```sh
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
Codename:   buster
```

When I just type the `docker pull flink`, there is an error called:

> ERROR: no matching manifest for linux/arm/v7 in the manifest list entries

How could I install it correctly? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please check this article. https://github.com/twiechert/docker-arm-flink

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem, and then searched for an ARMv7 compatible image and found this tag: `1.8-scala_2.12-alpine`. It is a few versions behind, but works on my k3s cluster on raspberry pi.